# What happens when your secret API key is stolen and used by others?

Tags: appsec, api

The use of paid API is increasingly rising each year. For example, IBM, Google and Microsoft are providing paid API such as *Text to Speech*, *Speech to Text* and *Image to Text* and vice versa.

I have a question about what happens If I build an app and publish it:

**1**.What happens when another person use Wireshack or reverse engineering to  obtain the key of this API and then use it in their app or sell it?

**2**.Will I be paying for this even though my clients are not the people using this API?

**3**.Is there a way to reduce or prevent this from happening?

I am just worried about this and sure this is happening or must have happened at some point.

**NOTE**:

I asked this because I saw my Google Map API with the Wireshark software.

My initial solution is to make each user create username and password and apply  restrictions to each individual user but those companies I mentioned up don't do that. They simply use one single key for their services.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to avoid it : instead of doing request directly to the api service, do them to your server which do them with the apikey to the api service.

Comment: I never thought about that. This means I need another server for the app. It would be good if you put this as answer.. I still need answer to other questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. As you may expect it, there is no way to fully protect your api key
   if it is directly used by a client application. The user can sniff his
   netowrk (the use of `https` or of an encrypted channel might still
   help but is only a matter of time as the user can see the full
   handshake) or reverse engeneering the software (same here, you can
   encrypt the api key but with some work, you can always get the key
   back).
2. Yes, you will still get charged even if the api key is not used accordingly to what you may expect simply because the api service has no way to know if it is some of your intented use.
3. There is only one solution which can fully secure your api key from being grabbed and used as not intended : do everything with the api key server side. Your server will act as proxy between the client application and the api service and thus, the client can't be aware of the api key. Howewer, it may cost you additional cost to set up a server.

Comment: Doing everythink on the server side will change nothing, just hide the api key but the hackers can still access the service at zero cost using your server !

Comment: @loki True but with this solution, you can implement login system for each user and add request limitation to each account and IP Address. You have control over how your API is used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling API from publicly open websites, there is no 100% secured solution. 
 
 You can make it difficult using encryption/decryption, obfuscation, proxies, some header checks, code changes on each build and all - but it won't be 100% secured. 
 
 Because whatever you've done can be easily reversed engineered by a good hacker as he can be the legitimate user and he doesn't need any valid login or IP to use publicly open websites, so he has access to all JavaScript/HTML code and he can monitor the network requests from website and analyze the pattern.

Comment: encryption/decryption wouldn't work here because they can be reversed. I am calling it from an app not website but even though it's from a website, Xavier59's answer would still work. You make the request from your server not on on the client.

Comment: Xavier59's answer would not work because your server side request can easily be captured by the network monitoring and hacker will just make the same request to your server and he would still get the expected data.

Comment: Also, if you're using native android/iPhone app, it's difficult to reverse encryption/decryption because hacker won't have direct access to your code unlike website. However, there're some de-compilers which may help the hacker to get the code.

Comment: No, my server is making the request. The request is done on my server, from my network. You can't capture it unless you're on my network but you're not. Your computer makes request to my server, my server then makes request to the API then returns the result to your computer. Is that hard to understand? It's not difficult to  reverse encryption/decryption on iOS. I was able to do so within minutes and get all the code I needed. You can do it during run-time and get the API code or any variable value so that's not even safe.

Comment: The only thing you can capture is the request from your computer to my server **not** the request from my server to the API server such as the Google Map server. My API key is still 100% private.

Comment: That's what I'm telling you - Hacker don't need to capture the API request from your server, he just need to capture the request from his computer to your server. Of course he won't get the API key, but he can make the same request to your server and get the same response.

Comment: And you're telling me that you reversed engineered .ipa file in Minutes ?? LOL - Even experts cannot do that in Minutes for good applications.

Comment: You kept talking about capturing network and I kept trying to tell you that's not possible..... *"Of course he won't get the API key"* That's why I asked this question and that has been solved. *"but he can make the same request to your server and get the same response"* Yes but with limitation since I have control over the request now, I can implement login for each user and impose restriction on the amount of requests made from each account and IP Addresses.

Comment: I talked about this yesterday [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/153142/what-happens-when-your-secret-api-key-is-stolen-and-used-by-others/196998?noredirect=1#comment391649_153144). It's something you can't do without your own server or with your encryption/decryption solution. Finally, for your "LOL" it's hard to reverse-engineer for the first time. Once you know what you're doing, it takes minutes to do that. It's usually a cmd stuff but most people doing this end up building a UI on top of the cmd program to make it automated. On my side, one click will do the job.

Comment: You need to see the bigger picture of problem. If your application is public, then 1000 employees of same office might be using your app using same IP. If you throttle requests based on IP, you might throttle such legitimate users. If your app is public - hacker can create so many accounts as well.

Comment: For different .ipa files, reverse engineering of app's algorithm will be different. So UI of reverse engineering one app's algorithm will not work for other app.

Comment: RE is done while the program is running on the iOS device. Yes, it can be automated and it is as I am typing this. There something called "Jailbreak" which makes it even easier to do this on the device. I will put this RE topic t rest since it's getting out of topic.

Comment: Yes it can be automated and you'll be able to see the source code, but understand that it'll still take time to understand the algorithm of the code - which is gonna be different for different app.

Comment: *"hacker can create so many accounts as well"* True, just like on Facebook, Stackoverflow, Twitter and many online games. This question is asked for a game that will use some paid API. It doesn't matter how many accounts they have. What matters is that I can ban accounts when there is a suspicious behavior detected from that account. This puts restriction to the amount of damage that can be done if my key is exposed. There are many ways to detect if account is related to another account. There would be false-positives but it can be done and has been.

Comment: Imagine no login required to play games online games? Hacking would be rampant and people will be getting away with them. The IP stuff I talked about is temporary ban/limit for a day and is also based on history of accounts from the-same IP. It can be done and again,  has been done and works fine. Finally, if you decrypt app, you have the encryption and decryption functions and can now use those functions to build another automated program and takes the encrypted data and spits out the real data.

Comment: You don't even have to do that. Just wait for the decrypt function to be called from the app then dump everything in the memory now I have the API key and that's that.

Comment: I guess that's what my answer means: It cannot be 100% secured and you cannot stop the misuse of API, of course you can make it difficult and reduce the possibilities of misuse.